# How to undo fastboot disable and CSM enable option in BIOS? currently have no display. Is clearing CMOS my only option?

Tags: bios, pci-express, cmos

So I just disabled fast boot and enabled CSM boot in order to try and get a windows 10 install USB to boot. The system won't boot now and I have no display.

Is CMOS reset my only option in this case? If I go that route are my SSD's in risk of corruption? Should I disconnect them before the CMOS reset? Also I have applied a BIOS update using the EZ update utility provided by ASUS a while back. will I need to re-apply this update upon reset?

I am currently using a gtx 770 gpu which has it's own UEFI BIOS, could this be the problem that is preventing the display from initializing and the system from POSTing

Because I am trying to dual boot with an existing windows 7 install,  I made the USB using Rufus, and I selected the MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI. The windows 10 install USB would boot from the UEFI option using the f8 menu, but I need to use legacy not UEFI. When using the legacy option from the f8 menu, the windows 10 install USB would initialize, and say "press any key  to boot..." ,  but when I would press enter, it would say "failed to start, press ctrl+alt+del to restart".

So like I Already mentioned, I disabled fast boot, and enabled CSM boot, to try and get the windows 10 install USB to boot/start. But now my PC/bios fails to POST. I have the ASUS Maximus VII Hero Z97 chipset motherboard. The mobo includes a Q-led display that displays startup and error codes. On a successful boot the code displayed is "AO" , which stands for "IDE initialization is started". As of now the system powers up but I have no display, and the code "92" is displayed, which stands for "PCI"  bus initialization is started" but it doesn't make it past that.

In Comment to @Rich Manson,
My motherboard is the  ASUS Maximus VII Hero with Z97 chipset. I was messing around with my windows 7 system a while back, and it failed to boot. I used the MBR repair option on the [Rescatux live GRUB/MBR repair CD](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) and it worked. Everytime I boot I see the letters MBR flash, then the loading splash screen for windows 7 comes up. That is why I believe my Windows 7 install is using the MBR scheme, and not the GPT scheme. Also when I initially installed Windows 7, the option I chose didn't say (UEFI) beside it on the boot options screen, so I thought choosing the other option means you are using legacy boot, which uses MBR instead of GPT. And I'm not trying to install a hybrid system, I am trying to install windows 10 with legacy boot/MBR since I supposedly already use the MBR scheme.

**Update,** It was indeed my graphics card that causing the system to stop on initialization of the PCI-E bus. I pulled my GPU's out and used the on-board graphics to revert the BIOS settings. CMOS reset wasn't necessary. And I had gotten the boot options that I changed confused. I had indeed disabled fast boot before the problem, but I had also **disabled** CSM boot, whereas it was actually already enabled beforehand. I was previously stating that I had enabled it. If I had left it enabled then I believe my display still would have worked.

[image]

Comment: Does your system board have on-board graphics? What is the model of your MB? Since Windows 7 installs in UEFI mode, why would you not want to use it? Setting up a gpu in MBR or some hybrid MBR is more complicated and less reliable.

Comment: Is it just the words MBR that flash or is there more to the message? I don't think you always see any UEFI boot option before installing. If a system board is set in UEFI mode and you boot to a UEFI install disk it will look for the UEFI boot files on the dvd or usb (whichever type of install media you are using ) and initiate a UEFI install provided your disk you are installing to is formatted GPT. If it isn't formatted GPT then the install will halt somewhere before Windows boots into setup. I am about to research if it is possible to change a Windows installed CSM mode to a UEFI boot system

Comment: Even if your GPU supports UEFI GOP, it will also support the legacy VGA BIOS scheme. It does *not* have “its own UEFI BIOS”.

Comment: @DanielB,If my graphics card doesn't have it's own UEFI BIOS, then would please explain the above image that I just added, which is of a paper that was included with my GPU from EVGA?

Comment: Well it's obviously bs. It does have a BIOS. It may be UEFI-compatible. That doesn't make it an UEFI BIOS though. That's what your *motherboard* has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resetting the CMOS** may not fix your issue or garner the results your looking to realize.  Also, resetting the CMOS should not effect data on an SSD. But to answer your other question, Yes you can unplug them if it worries you. Resetting CMOS just resets the system setup to default.

**You mentioned your gpu has its own UEFI** and that you enabled CSM boot after it was installed. It sounds like you set up the gpu in UEFI mode and you then switched to UEFI/Legacy/CSM mode. This would prevent your graphics from initializing and the display to not be working. Your particular system board, ASUS MAXIMUS VII HERO, has on-board graphics. To get you gpu to show a display or initialize, you could try pulling out the gpu and see if on-board graphics work to get into setup. UEFI boards have a basic graphics driver to enable on-board graphics.

**Make sure you set your system up in one mode**

You will need to set up the hardware and software (OS) in the same system mode. You can't set up part of your system in one mode and switch to another mode since this would imply trying to get the system board to run in both modes at the same time, which it will not.

**Windows 7 is documented to be able to install in UEFI mode.** You are getting the "failed to start, press ctrl+alt+del to restart" message because it is not finding some boot files either because there are not where they should be or corrupt, or they appear to not be there because the system is looking in the wrong place. This could be simply a setup setting that is wrong as this can also generate this message.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53310/discussion-on-answer-by-rich-manson-how-to-undo-fastboot-disable-and-csm-enable).